# Adding a second mouse cursor controller by a second device to a cocoa application

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a system with two simultaneous users, an experimenter and a subject.  The experimenter needs to maintain control of the system.  The subject needs to provide pointing/mouse cursor input without taking control away from the experimenter.

Is it possible with the cocoa framework to add a second mouse cursor that is controlled by a second mouse device? The second mouse need only be one button.

If a second mouse is possible could I implement it to generate `NSEvent` objects that can be identified as separate from the primary mouse events.

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: No you cannot do that: http://superuser.com/questions/649325/two-mice-two-pointers-one-mac

Comment: Thank you @Eric J., your link led me to this: [link]https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/HID/intro/intro.html and this: [link]http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/, both of which might let me do what I want.

Although receiving `NSEvent` objects still seem to be out of the question.